# Present UIViewController in non-modal way?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have a UIViewController (called A), but sometimes I need to show a second UIViewController (called B) ,  cause I dont wanna disturb the UI actions in A( A still need to respond to some touch actions ), so is there any methods to show B in non-modal way?

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
[self addChildViewController:viewControllerB];
[self.view addSubview:viewControllerB.view];
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you can display a view controller in a non-modal way in Swift:

```
let newController = RegisterController()
self.addChildViewController(newController)
self.view.addSubview(newController.view)
```

Remove view in a non-modal way:

```
view.removeFromSuperview()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily embed any viewcontroller in another. check it out:

[iOS Nested View Controllers view inside UIViewController's view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499391/ios-nested-view-controllers-view-inside-uiviewcontrollers-view)

Answer (score 1):

You can embed B in A as a child view.

For an exhaustive description see http://subjective-objective-c.blogspot.co.uk/2011/08/writing-high-quality-view-controller.html, for a simple demo, check out this code: https://github.com/toolmanGitHub/stackedViewControllers

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are talking about presenting view controllers modally in iPhone. In iPad, just for the sake of completeness in the example, you have more ways to show a view controller modally that doesn't fill the whole screen.

You can use UIViewController containment for this.
All in all it's just adding a view controller as a child of another while adding it's view to the hierarchy.
Check this tutorial at [obj.io](http://www.objc.io/issue-1/containment-view-controller.html). This is what @Justafinger is suggesting but complete instead as @Justafinger forgot some important calls.

Answer (score 0):

You can

> addChildViewController

like this -

```
- (void)loadContentView
    {
        CGFloat ht               = 0; // height you want to change;
        HomeAdsTVC_iPhone   *vc1 = [[HomeAdsTVC_iPhone alloc] init];
        [self addChildViewController:vc1];
        CGRect frame             = self.view.bounds;
        frame.origin.y           = ht;
        frame.size.height        -= ht;
        vc1.view.frame           = self.view.bounds;
        [self.view addSubview:vc1.view];
        [vc1 didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    }
```