# Show combine two View Controller in one screen

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, segue, uistoryboard

I have a screen like this.

[image: first screen]

I want to show a view like in below picture on the image view when user click tab bar item. Now I'm doing it by giving "-" constraints and when user click one of the tab bar item. I changed - constraint to + constraint. However, I'm not sure if there is a better way to do it. 
[image]

Comment: you can use hidden property of view to show and hide the view instead of changing constraints of view.

Comment: But the problem is I'll also add uicollectionview and tableview in that white area. Therefore, it will be hard to design it.

Comment: you should be using the view controller containment pattern. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499391/ios-nested-view-controllers-view-inside-uiviewcontrollers-view