# How to add a UIViewController as a subview to a UIViewController(RootViewController)?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, addsubview

I have a `UIViewController` named `LoginViewController`, and it is a `rootViewController` in the `AppDelegate`. In the `LoginViewController`, I have two buttons: `Login` and `Enroll`.

When I tap `Login`, I assign a `TabBarController` as the `rootViewController`, then show the `TabBarController`. However, now I think I need to add another `UIViewcController` as a subview when I tap `Enroll`. I tried the following:

```
[self.view addsubview:viewcontroller.view];
```

But the problem here is **My ViewController's view.top is pinned about 20 pixels below the top of the screen**. I think there is an issue with the status bar, but I can't figure out how to fix it.

**I think that I need to add my ViewController as a subview to the LoginViewController**, then redirect from there to different views. Can someone please suggest other options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not make a UIViewController a subview of another UIViewController's view.  What you likely want to do if treat the subview as a normal UIView (if not both of those views) so that you only have one UIViewController on screen and it occupies the entire screen.

More here: [How to add an UIViewController's view as subview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486832/how-to-add-an-uiviewcontrollers-view-as-subview)

Answer (score 2):

Try to set frame to your enroll screen object then add it as a subview to loginview. 
Ex:

```
[enrollViewcontroller.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,440)];
[self.view addsubview:enrollViewcontroller.view];
```

Comment: change the frame according to your requirement. Because it is 20 pixel down try to change the y axis position like this CGRectMake(0,-20,320,440) and check.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding a UIViewController as a subview to another UIViewController, I have decided to present my ViewController as a ModalViewController using

```
[self presentModalViewController:myViewController animated:YES];
```