# Can i add one view in to another?

Tags: ios, objective-c

i had learned objective C 2 weeks ago, i get a project to front end, and i had stuck with one problem. I have my own class instead of default UITableView. With help of these class was created controller, let it be UniversalViewNavigationController, which show some table with content in cells, and i have a MainViewController where these cells show in popover. I need to show these tableView like simple table view, in my view, not in popover, how can i do these?

P.S. Sorry for my English, i hope you understand me :)

How it init's now
MainController

.h file

```
UIPopoverController *objectsTableViewPopover;
```

.m file, ViewDidLoad

```
 UniversalViewNavigationController *tablePopoverVC = [[UniversalViewNavigationController alloc] initWithTableSize:CGSizeMake(300, 550)];
    tablePopoverVC.delegate = self;
    objectsTableViewPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:tablePopoverVC];
    objectsTableViewPopover.popoverContentSize = tablePopoverVC.viewSize;
```

and IBAction

```
-(IBAction)navigationButtonClick:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *tappedButton = (UIButton *)sender;

    [objectsTableViewPopover presentPopoverFromRect:tappedButton.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Have you tried a container view?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add an UIViewController's view as subview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486832/how-to-add-an-uiviewcontrollers-view-as-subview)

Comment: I have edited description of my problem, i don't really know if a need to use container view, how to add view to container view programmatically? and better to add container in storyboard or in code? Thank's.

Comment: In there anything in the [View Controller Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html) that helps you? Particularly the section on Container View Controllers?

Comment: I think there is anything but i'm to young programer to understand it, and it's all in English. So i wrote here in hope that somebody helps me :)

Comment: In which case the two answers below should work. You should be using the storyboard, and you should be using container view controllers, but it will take you a bit of time to learn about them. The answers you get from here will also be in English, so I'm not sure what more help I can give you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do this

```
[mainViewController.view addSubView:exampleViewController.view];
```

You may need to adjust the frame.

Comment: @Tarek leave nothing to the imagination I guess ;-)

Comment: hh, man in other situation people usually downvote ;)

Comment: @Abizern good point, updated.

Comment: The addSubview needs to be like this not like how you have it .

Answer (score 1):

```
UIView *view = exampleViewController.view; // or exampleViewController.tableView;
[mainViewController.view addSubView:view];
```

Comment: should be [mainViewComtroller.view addSubView:view];