# Adding a UIViewController to a UIView

Tags: objective-c, uistoryboard, iboutlet

I have `ViewcontrollerA` , which is a view made in `storyboard`.
In this view, i have a `UIView` that i have added in `storyboard` and create an outlet to it called `containerView`.

I wants to add some other `viewControllerB` (also made in `storyboard`) to the container.

Tried that :

```
//add to container a new view from storyboard,with id called serviceView
UIViewController *sv = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ServiceView"];
[self.containerView addSubview:sv.view];
```

and got a crash.

How can i do that ?

Thanks .

Comment: This might help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486832/how-to-add-an-uiviewcontrollers-view-as-subview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It most likely crashed because `sv` is `nil`, though you should have posted what reason it gave for the crash in your question. If this is the reason, it's probably because your storyboard doesn't contain a view controller with that storyboard identifier. But even if you fixed this, this isn't the proper way of doing view controller containment.

As for adding a view controller to another view controller, you need to use the view controller containment API added in iOS 5. In fact you can even use the storyboard to do view controller containment without writing code. From the Object Library, you can drag out a "Container View". It will let you attach another view controller from your storyboard graphically.

Comment: wow it works great ! thanks a lot man! can you direct me on how to load/remove the views in the container with animation ?