# How to show a ViewController with Xib in Another ViewController as a SubView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I have one `Base Class` I have inherited my `Parent Class` from this `Base Class`.

Now I have another `ViewController` With `XIB`. All I want is to present This `XIB as` a View in my Parent Class.

Name of My `ViewController` With XIB is: **`SearchResultDisplayVC`**

This code I am using my Base Class to Show My XIB as a View:

```
 - (void)showSearchResultsView
 {

SearchResultDisplayVC  *searchView =(SearchResultDisplayVC *)[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SearchResultDisplayVC" owner:[SearchResultDisplayVC class] options:nil] firstObject];


[self.view addSubview:searchView.view];

}
```

In my Parent class I am calling it as"

```
[self showSearchResultsView];
```

Although I am not getting any error message in compile time but when I run my App it crashes showing the following message:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
'NSUnknownKeyException',
reason: '[<SearchResultDisplayVC 0x1104bb380> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key view.'
```

Comment: Yes you are adding ViewController as View "`addSubView`".

Comment: how I can I add it as a subView or is their any other way of doing @the_UB

Comment: Check [Micky's and others answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486832/how-to-add-an-uiviewcontrollers-view-as-subview).

Comment: you should check first object you are receiving from nib.i guess that is itself a view instead of your view controller.if thats a view you can simply add it to current view

Answer (score 1):

you have to add as child view controller in the parent view.

```
  SearchResultDisplayVC * searchView = [[SearchResultDisplayVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"SearchResultDisplayVC" bundle:nil];
    self.addChildViewController(searchView)
```

---

Comment: After adding how to subview

Answer (score 1):

Please modify your "showSearchResultsView" as:

```
- (void)showSearchResultsView
 {

UIView  *searchView =(SearchResultDisplayVC *)[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SearchResultDisplayVC" owner:[SearchResultDisplayVC class] options:nil] firstObject];


[self.view addSubview:searchView];

}
```

Comment: thanks for your response ..but when I run this code I am getting warning

Answer (score 1):

You have got a problem with your SearchResultDisplayVC.xib file I hope, Check the outlet connection for view in the file's owner it should be set to the main view for any view controller to work. Like below,

[image]

All view controllers expect a "view" object to be defined and mapped from nib files. You have a view controller nib but there is no outlet called "view" in it. Otherwise whatever code you have written would work well.

Answer (score 0):

After so many research finally I found a way to Add it to `window`.

Now I can user `viewDidLoad` and all other methods also.

```
- (void)showSearchResultsView
{

if(!self.searchDisplayView){

    self.searchDisplayView = [[SearchResultDisplayVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"SearchResultDisplayVC" bundle:nil];

    self.searchDisplayView.delegate = self;


    CGSize mainScreenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;

    self.searchDisplayView.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,
                                               0,
                                               mainScreenSize.width,
                                               mainScreenSize.height);
}

AppDelegate *delegate =  (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[delegate.window addSubview:self.searchDisplayView.view];


 }
```