# UIButton in a subview not response to touch events with objective-c

Tags: ios, uibutton, subview

I want to create a bottom tab that could change the view when user press.

To do that I create a view with view controller and sets it's frame in the init

Here is the bottom panel view controller

```
@implementation BottomTabViewController

-(id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{
    if(self = [super init]){
        self.view.frame = frame;
        return self;
    }else{
        return nil;
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setUpButtons];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

-(void) featureBtnClick:(id*) sender{
    NSLog(@"featureBtn Clicked");
}

-(void) favBtnClick:(id*)sender{
    NSLog(@"Fav Btn Clicked");
}

-(void) setUpButtons{
    UIButton *features = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 50, 50)];
    [features setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"feature.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    features.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

    [features addTarget:self action:@selector(featureBtnClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:features];

    UIButton *favBtn = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake([[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.width - 100, 10, 50, 50)];
    [favBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"favorite.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [favBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(favBtnClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    favBtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

    [self.view addSubview:favBtn];

}


@end
```

And I added that to my view with code like this:

```
-(void) setUpBottom{

    BottomTabViewController *botm = [[BottomTabViewController alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height - 55, [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.width, 55)];
    botm.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
   // botm.view.userInteractionEnabled = false;
    botm.view.userInteractionEnabled = true;
    [self.view addSubview:botm.view];
}
```

Here here is the result seems, note the bottom panel that works, well pretty silly, but it shows up:

[image]
But when press the left and right button, there is not log printed which it expected to be to indict that the button works, What have I done wrong? Thanks

Comment: Try to replace code of subview  https://stackoverflow.com/a/13617590/4601900 and also set color to buttons too to test

Comment: Why you have created UIViewController class, you are adding UIView.

Comment: thanks for reply @MikeAlter Have tried to add color to the buttons, and its turn out pretty expected, will check the link you give for more info.

Comment: @AdityaSrivastava hmm, let me try that

Comment: can you check your view hierarchy to debug if theres a view overlapping

Comment: @Joshua hey, not sure how to check that, just edit the problem and upload a new screenshot with the buttons in another color, check that out :D

Comment: @armnotstrong Have you used UIView instead of UIViewController?

Comment: theres a debug hierarchy along with the enable/disable breakpoint. Anyway if its not hierarchy overlapped Im thinking of delegate already deallocated so target wont respond anymore, just my thought. maybe make botm as an instance variable and verify from there?

Comment: The intent of the UIViewController is to drive the entire screen. Why don't  use UIView to handle it?

Answer (score 0):

you are adding buttons in the view first then adding the bottom view.
if this is what you are doing then it can be overlapped by the bottom view.
In this case buttons cant be tapped because they have bottom view on top of them.
so make sure u add bottom view first then your buttons. (or change their frames to avoid overlapping)

Comment: `setUpButtons` was invoked in the `viewDidLoad ` so I think maybe the order of adding the button is good?

Comment: add bottomView first and then add buttons